# How to inject HTML file into another HTML file in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to inject(or import html file) into another HTML file in Django. Of course, I tried to do it, but I am getting errors below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNxYW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4qvO.png)

TemplateDoesNotExist at /
fanduel.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.10
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
fanduel.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\j\Desktop\Project\Python\p\website\webenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py, line 84, in reraise
Python Executable:  C:\Users\j\Desktop\Project\Python\p\website\webenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.0

I built the code like this.

```
    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>FanDuel</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <!-- start row-->
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-center">
        {% include 'fanduel.html' %}
      </div>
    <!-- end row -->
    </div>
```

Of course, there is a fanduel.html file in the same level directory.
I am not sure what I am wrong.
I hope anyone knows what my issue is.

Thank you in advice.

Comment: You have to specify the path to the inner HTML file the same way you would do it from your views.py. I mean, if you call `render` with a path like `<folder_name>/index.html`, you must include the 'fanduel.html' from your template saying `<folder_name>/fanduel.html`. Are you doing so?

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, but  I think, I did something like this.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/23pm6qp

Comment: Hello @SherlockBourne, thank you. Can you put any example for me? I am not good at Django. Thank you again.

Comment: Ah, I just modified the code something like this.  {% include 'website/fanduel.html' %}  So the errors are gone.

Comment: Yes exactly, that was what I meant before :)

Comment: Hi @SherlockBourne, I want to vote up for you now.

Comment: Do not worry! As the solution has been reached in the comments, we do not need an answer where you can vote up. We can leave it like this without any problem :)

Comment: You are welcome! I will post an answer with the solution anyway, so if anyone has the same doubt/problem they can see it without reading the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

As found out in the comments of the original question, it is important to also specify the folder in which the template is stored, just like we do when telling the `render` function the template to render.

That being said, instead of:

`{% include 'fanduel.html' %}`

It has to be:

`{% include 'website/fanduel.html' %}`